# Springboot java: class file has wrong version 61.0, should be 55.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, google-app-engine

I'm migrating my legacy Google Appengine from java 8 to java 11. I'm using maven and for localhost testing it has been simple to use mvn appengine:run.
From what I've read this HTTP server doesn't work with java 11, and google docs has directed me to Springboot. Firstly, is that the simplest migration, or is there a simple way to get appengine:run to work with java 11?

Sadly, when I following the example in the google docs: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java-gen2/building-app/writing-web-service the Spring Initialzr creates a pom.xml file for java 17 (even though I selected java 11). I edited the example pom.xml file to be java 11 and get the following error when I run: mvn spring-boot:run

```
bad class file:.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\3.0.6\spring-boot-3.0.6.jar
class file has wrong version 61.0, should be 55.0
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath
```

From further reading it says that Springboot v6 needs java 17 and for java 11 I need 5.3 - But how do I force it to use this older version.

Thanks!
Tim

Comment: The max spring boot version 2.7.11 which requires minimum JDK8+... otherwise you have to upgrade JDK17+ and use Spring Boot 3.X ...

Answer (score 4):

Change spring-boot-starter-parent version

```
    <version>2.7.11</version>
```

Comment: Why such an old verison.. the minimum Spring Boot 2.7.11 supports JDK8+

Comment: I think it was just an example, but 2.7.11 works too. Thanks. Pity the spring boot initialise has bugs in it when you select java 11 :-(